# Jssor Scrolling Logo Slider - Set Width at 100% of Parent Div?

Tags: jssor

I'd like to set the width of my Jssor scrolling logo slider to 100% of the parent div rather than 980px. Seems that there are other things in play where if I adjust the jssor_1 div to 100%, it doesn't actually increase the width, just tries to fit everything in 980px.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer. For anybody else with this, change the following line:

```
refSize = Math.min(refSize, 809);
```

to:

```
refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1980);
```